# How to copy files from local machine to digital ocean droplet?

Tags: digital-ocean

I have a folder which contains many files and i want to copy it to digital ocean droplet from local ubuntu terminal.

Answer (score 3):

You can zip all the files and make it as single file to make the process easier and you can use **SCP**

```
scp files.zip remote_username@IP-ADDRESS:/remote/directory/tocopy
```

I hope this is just a copy process and not deployment.. **SCP** is not recommended for deployments